# Pdf damaged on download

Tags: php, pdf, download, dompdf

I've got a web from that has two buttons for submitting, one sends an email with pdf attached, this works perfectly.

The second button is to download the pdf, this is the problem. I am saving the pdf in a temp file before download but after it is downloaded the file doesn't open and it is corrupt. The pdf is about 30KB. I have tried solutions to similar questions but always the same result, the pdf won't open.

This didn't work

```
    $fileName = "file.pdf";
    $file_name = ("temp/file.pdf");
    file_put_contents($file_name, $pdf_content);

    $filepath=$file_name; //file location
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
```

This didn't work

```
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/temp/"; // change the path to fit your websites document structure
    $fullPath = $path.$fileName;

    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; 
    filename='.basename($fullPath));
    header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header('Content-Length: '. filesize($fullPath));
    readfile($fullPath);
    exit;
```

This didn't work

```
    set_time_limit(0); // disable timeout
    $file = $root_path.'/full-tile-book.pdf';
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="NewName.pdf"');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    $f = fopen($file, 'rb');
    fpassthru($f);
    fclose($f);
    exit;
```

This didn't work

```
    header('Pragma: public');  // required
    header('Expires: 0');  // no cache
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Cache-Control: private', false);
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($filepath)) . ' GMT');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=file.pdf');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding:  binary");
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath)); // provide file size
    header('Connection: close');
    readfile($filepath);
    exit();
```

The file is always in the temp folder on the server and that works fine so somewhere in the download the file is getting corrupted.

I don't care how the download is done, pdf or oclet-stream or any other way.

Comment: Never mind found the problem, there was a php error creating the pdf (and i couldn't see it because the pdf wouldn't open). The pdf worked with the email attachment but not downloading it, I can't understand that but it works now! I found the error by opening the pdf in notepad++ if anyone else has a problem they should do this to see the error.

Comment: This is a common issue. If errors are sent to the browser they can be caught in the output stream when the PDF is being rendered. You should disable sending errors to the browser when using dompdf (at the very least) and use the PHP error log.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. The errors weren't there when the pdf was sent as a email so I thought the pdf was ok and was looking for the wrong problem. All good now though.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the : Content-Type header and it works for me.

Regards